# React - useState only affecting last property value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to set `validPassword` and `validFormData` values to false whenever a form is submited and the values are empty. I'm calling this function on submit but it's only changing the last property in my useState

```
const [validPassword, setValidPassword] = useState({
    password: true,
    confirmPassword: true
})
const [validFormData, setValidFormData] = useState({
    email: true,
    name: true,
    lastName: true,
    phone: true,
 })

const signupAction = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (formData.email === "" || formData.name === "" || formData.lastName === "" || formData.phone === "" || formData.password === "" || formData.confirmPassword === "") {
            for (let p in formData) {
                if (formData[p] === "") {
                    if (p === "password" || p === "confirmPassword") {
                        setValidPassword({ ...validPassword, [p]: false })
                    } else {
                        setValidFormData({ ...validFormData, [p]: false })
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            console.log('success')
        }
        /* signup(formData, history) */
    }
```

What I get from this is:

```
validPassword = {
  password: true,
  confirmPassword: false
}
validFormData = {
   email: true,
   name: true,
   lastName: true,
   phone: false,
}
```

Comment: Do you have a example to reproduce the issue, in Codesandbox or fiddle?

Comment: Basically you are calling setState in a loop, which is a bit ugly. If posiible prepapre an Object inside the loop, once the loop is done assign the Object as state.

Comment: Use the functional form of the setter instead of the direct form using the current value: `setValidPassword(actualValidPassword => {/* Your function */})`.  The committers are "lazy" and you will just be acting on the last value otherwise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: Setting state in a loop is bad practice and it's expensive. Because for every setState the component will re render. you can create your data set in loop. And setState with those data after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setState` function is `async`. The common pattern of setting a state which is the one you are using is not fool proof one. One should use `callback` based setting state to by pass these common issues. Code like below would work

```
const signupAction = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (formData.email === "" || formData.name === "" || formData.lastName === "" || formData.phone === "" || formData.password === "" || formData.confirmPassword === "") {
        for (let p in formData) {
            if (formData[p] === "") {
                if (p === "password" || p === "confirmPassword") {
                    setValidPassword((prevState) => ({...prevState, [p]: false }))
                } else {
                    setValidFormData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [p]: false }))
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        console.log('success')
    }
    /* signup(formData, history) */
}
```

Further, to prevent multiple updates, it is best if you store the changes in the loop in a local variable and set all at once like below

```
const signupAction = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (formData.email === "" || formData.name === "" || formData.lastName === "" || formData.phone === "" || formData.password === "" || formData.confirmPassword === "") {
        const tempValidPassword = { ...validPassword};
        const tempValidFormData = { ...validFormData};
        for (let p in formData) {
            if (formData[p] === "") {
                if (p === "password" || p === "confirmPassword") {
                    tempValidPassword[p] = false;
                } else {
                    tempValidFormData[p] = false;
                }
            }
        }
        setValidPassword(tempValidPassword);
        setValidFormData(tempValidFormData);
    } else {
        console.log('success')
    }
    /* signup(formData, history) */
}
```

**Note:** These are only pesudo-code. Fit according to your needs. Try to use `functional updates` to state as mentioned [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) whenever possible

Comment: Thanks! I created the constants and then updated with `setState()`. Works perfectly!