# React useState not updating all property except when using loops

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am validating form from server side. once I get error message, I wants to show error message on respective textbox field's error message

**client side Object**

```
const formFields = {
    firstName: {
        helperText: '',
        error: false
    },
    lastName: {
        helperText: '',
        error: false
    },
    emailID: {
        helperText: '',
        error: false
    },
    phoneNo: {
        helperText: '',
        error: false
    },
    password: {
        helperText: '',
        error: false
    },
    confirmPassword: {
        helperText: '',
        error: false
    }
}
```

**Server side response object after validation**

```
const responseError = errorData.response.data.errors //below object is the response
//{
    //"LastName": ["Enter LastName"],
    //"FirstName": ["Enter FirstName"],
    //"ConfirmPassword": ["Enter Confirm Password","confirm password do not match"]
//}
```

**useState**

```
const [inpValues, setInpValues] = useState(formFields)
```

**Conditions to update**

if ClientSideObj.key === responseObj.key then setInpValues of error and helperText field

```
const responseError = errorData.response.data.errors
console.log(responseError)

var FormFieldName = ""
for (keys in formFields) {
    console.log('FormField keys = ' + keys)

    for (var errorKeys in responseError) {
        if (keys.toLowerCase() === errorKeys.toLowerCase()) {

            console.log('* MATCHED FIELDS = ' + errorKeys) 
            //Matched 3 fields(LastName,FirstName,ConfirmPassword) successfully

            FormFieldName = keys
            
                    
            setInpValues(prevInpValues => ({
                ...prevInpValues,
                [FormFieldName]: {
                    ...prevInpValues[FormFieldName],
                    error: true,
                    helperText: responseError[errorKeys]
                    }
                })
            )
            console.table(inpValues)
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**

> I go through this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63377715/react-usestate-only-affecting-last-property-value) already, then I passed previousState values also. still result same.

> It's updating only the last for loop condition value

> If the response.error object has return only one field, then it's updating that one

Comment: use `let` and `const` instead of `var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's updating only the last for loop condition value

- [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1451009/6567275)
- [What is the difference between "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/762011/6567275)

as [Miguel Hidalgo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74248169/6567275) states, you should make all changes in one update:

```
const responseError = errorData.response.data.errors
console.log(responseError)

setInpValues(state => {
  const newState = { ...state };
  for (let errorKey in responseError) {
    for (let formField in formFields) {
      // this would be so much simpler if your properties would be in the correct case and you'd not have to do this dance with `.toLowerCase()`
      if (formField.toLowerCase() !== errorKey.toLowerCase()) {
        continue;
      }

      newState[formField] = {
        ...newState[formField],
        error: true,
        helperText
      }
    }
  }

  return newState
});
```

If `errorKey` and `fieldName` would be identical and you'd not have to match them case insensitive you could write this:

```
const responseError = errorData.response.data.errors
console.log(responseError)

setInpValues(state => {
  const newState = { ...state };
  for (let formField in responseError) {
    newState[formField] = {
      ...newState[formField],
      error: true,
      helperText: responseError[formField]
    }
  }
  return newState
});
```

Comment: thanks for your time. both you and @miguel are working. but could you please tell me why do you make `newState` object and return that `newState` instead of directly update the `prevState` like @miguel mentioned.

Comment: one more question to understand how the logic works. Why it didn't update when I setValues inside loop?. I setValues once the loop condition is satisfied, but it doesn't update. but you use the loop inside the setValue, that is only difference

Comment: @Liamneesan I've linked you two related questions in this answer. The issue is a combination of `var`, loops and any kind of async code, wether it's Promises, callbacks, Events, or whatever. It's working inside the `setInpValues` because 1. I use `let` and `const` and 2. `var` would now be used synchronously. Please read up on the differences between `let`/`const` and `var`, `hoisting` and why in the past there were so many IIFEs inside of loops.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do in order to avoid unnecessary extra renders its to loop inside setState callback:

```
setInpValues(prevInpValues => {

    for (const formKey in formFields) {
     
      for (const errorKey in responseError) {
          if (formKey.toLowerCase() === errorKey.toLowerCase()) {

              prevInpValues[formKey] = {
                ...prevInpValues[formKey],
                error: true,
                helperText: responseError[errorKey]
              }
          }
      }
  }
return {...prevInpValues}
}
```

Comment: 1. you're mutating the current state; don't . Then you're returning a copy so that `setInpValues` triggers a rerender. Turn that around, make the copy first and then mutate and return that copy. 2. You have mismatching brackets and your `return` is inside the loop.